# How to get computer device manager information as text result in cpp code?

Tags: c++, device-manager

How to get computer device manager information (in Windows (especially win 10)) as text result in cpp code?. In addition I don't want to use registry i my code.

Comment: What operating system ?

Comment: Windows (especially win 10)

Answer (score 1):

You can get information of device manager using Windows Management Instrumentation(WMI) or by using Setup APIs. One example of Setup APIs for getting device manager information can be found in [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14469/Simple-Device-Manager).